# Sinatra and Subdirectory Templates

Tags: templates, sinatra

Any chance Sinatra can have subdirectory templates in the `/views` directory?  Here's an example of **/views/companies/alphaco.erb**.  It's the route that I'm confused about.  `erb :alphaco` throws an ISE.

```
views:
  ajax.erb
  alpha.erb
  bravo.erb
  charlie.erb
  companies:
    alphaco.erb
  delta.erb
  echo.erb
  layout.erb
  nav.erb
  test.erb
```

Comment: Have you tried `erb :"companies/alphaco"` ?

Comment: Ah that worked!  So what is that?  Is that a symbol or a string?  Introduction of symbols is indeed confusing.

Comment: That's a symbol. That syntax comes in handy quite a lot.

Comment: `:symbol` is a `symbol`, which I use often.  You have quotation marks in there.

Comment: `:"companies/alphaco" == "companies/alphaco".to_sym`. Otherwise the parser would have to contend with characters that may be part of the symbol string or may be a method call.

Comment: OK that makes much more sense.  Thank you.